# iPad multitasking view transition effect

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, view, transition

I downloaded some application from the App store to my iPhone that have several views in it.
I saw that the developer did a transition effect between two views like the multitasking on the iPad effect, that one view goes behind the other.
I wondered... how can i accomplish that in my project code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are they made custom animations. I would first suggest that you take a look at the [Apple guide on Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html). Then [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes) has a good tutorial on animating a UIView. Check those two resources out and they should get you started with animations. Once you have a understanding of it, you should be able to re-create those animations.